# Exclude function from running on a certain page

Tags: php, functions

I'm working on modifying the Keyboard Shortcut Navigation plugin to fit my site. Here's the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-keyboard-shortcut-navigation/

I don't want this plugin to run on page 2020. I've tried `&& !is_page('2020')` and `|| !is_page('2020')` in the `elseif` below, but it keeps running the function.

Any ideas?

**Edit update**: As requested, I'm removing the snippet and including the full code from the plugin located at the above URL.

```
add_action('wp_footer','keyboard_shortcut_navigation');
function keyboard_shortcut_navigation(){
    global $paged, $wp_query;
    if ( !$max_page )
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ( !$paged )
        $paged = 1;
    $nextpage = intval($paged) + 1;
?>
<?php if( is_single() ) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = chang_page;function chang_page(e) {
    var e = e || event,
    keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var obj = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase()=="textarea"){return;}
    if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input"){return;}
    if (keycode == 33 || keycode == 37) location = '<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); ?>';
    if (keycode == 34 || keycode == 39) location = '<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>';
    }
</script>
<?php elseif( is_home() || is_category() ) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = chang_page;function chang_page(e) {
        var e = e || event,
        keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var obj = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase()=="textarea"){return;}
        if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input"){return;}
        if (keycode == 33 || keycode == 37) location = '<?php echo get_previous_posts_page_link(); ?>';
        if (keycode == 34 || keycode == 39) 
        <?php if ( $nextpage <= $max_page ) : ?>
            location = '<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>';
        <?php else : ?>
            location = '<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $max_page ); ?>';  
        <?php endif; ?>
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Please post more code. How/where that snippet gets hooked is important.

Comment: Will do, wasn't sure if it was OK to post another authors plugin code? I'll edit my question with the code as requested.

Comment: Is this site publicly accessible? Do you have an URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for a page on my site with ID 675:

```
function tst($content) {
  if (is_page(675)) print('howdy');
}
add_action('wp_footer','tst');
```

I would just interrupt the function right at the top.

```
function keyboard_shortcut_navigation(){
    global $paged, $wp_query;
    if (is_page(2020)) return; // for a post with ID 2020
    if (is_page('2020')) return; // for a post with slug or title "2020"
    // you should only need one of those
    // ... the rest
```

If you are talking a posts instead of pages then maybe what you want is this:

```
// old
<?php if( is_single() ) : ?>
// new
<?php if( is_single() && !is_single(2020)) : ?>
// use quotes if 2020 is the title or the slug
```

You are hacking somebody else's plugin so you are likely to have problems when you update. I'd contact the author and ask for a hook in the next release that will allow you to do this without hacking anything.

Comment: I put in both of those `is_page` examples to test it out, and the javascript is still loading on my page 2020. It's very strange, your tst function didn't work either. Since I'm looking for a little customization, and to prevent update problems, I've copied this to my functions.php, would that make a difference?

Comment: I ran that function from functions.php. Is the original plugin still active?

Comment: Nope, not active. What's weird is I've done this before, but for some reason it's not cooperating for me today. I wasn't able to get a howdy to print, and the javascript still ran on page 2020.

Comment: I copied that whole block of code into my functions.php and it works as expected. Are you sure you are talking about a page and not a post?

Comment: Yeah, its listed under the Pages section. I'm also sure it's page 2020, since in the URL it shows `post=2020&action=edit`

Comment: I see your modified answer, which also didn't help. I modified the original code under the `<?php elseif( is_home() || is_category() ) : ?>`, and those changes were shown, so I know this section is being represented on page 2020. Perhaps there's a modification that can take place in this half?

Comment: That is page ID 2020, so no quotes. What you are describing is odd because even unmodified, that code really shouldn't output anything to Pages at all, except if your blog page is assigned to a Page.

Comment: I do have a separate front page, and blog page if that's what you mean?